# python pandas outlier removal - can't remove due to an error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am tryimg to remove outliers with the command:

```
data = data[(np.abs(stats.zscore(data)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

but i get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

my data types are:

```
0        float64
1        float64
2        float64
3        float64
4        float64
5           int8
6          int64
7        float64
8        float64
9          int64
10       float64
11       float64
12       float64
13        object
14        object
15       float64
16       float64
17       float64
18          int8
19          int8
20       float64
21       float64
22         int64
23       float64
24       float64
label      int64
dtype: object
```

is there anyhow can I fix this?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is because columns 13 is an object. you have to exclude it:

```
columns_ok = [i[0] for i in data.dtypes.iteritems() if i[-1] != object]
data = data[(np.abs(stats.zscore(data[columns_ok])) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```